# try with resources - parameterized PreparedStatements

Tags: java, prepared-statement

**Edit** The suggested answer is unacceptable, can't have declaring additional methods for each method I've, imagine?. There must be a nested try with resources solution.

How can you use try statement with a prepare statement taking parameters?

I've the error with following two lines.

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid);
preparedStatement.setString(2, emailAddress);
```

> Error Declaration final or effectively final variable exepcted

```
public UserBean getUserDevices(final String emailAddress, final String uuid) throws SQLException {
    UserBean userBean = null;

    String query = "SELECT user.id, user.emailAddress, device.uuid, device.active, device.user_id FROM user " +
            "LEFT JOIN device ON user.id = device.user_id AND device.uuid = ? " +
            "WHERE user.emailAddress = ?";

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
         preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid);
         preparedStatement.setString(2, emailAddress);
         ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    ) {
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            if(userBean == null) { // initialize user once while iterating for devices
                userBean = new UserBean(resultSet.getInt("user.id"), resultSet.getString("user.emailAddress"), null);
            }
            if(resultSet.getString("device.uuid") != null) { // if device exists (it's a LEFT JOIN) then add
                userBean.getDevices().add(new DeviceBean(0, resultSet.getString("device.uuid"), resultSet.getBoolean("device.active"), resultSet.getInt("device.user_id")));
            }
        }
    }
    return userBean;
}
```

Comment: These two lines of code should be inside the try block. Not in the parentheses preceding the try block.

Comment: The idea of using try-with-resources is to be used when instantiating classes that implement Closeable.  Move the code into the try block

Comment: resultSet and preparedStatements are both closable, I want to utilize automatic closing with try resources, is there a way to use with inner outer try resources?

Comment: We both told you how to proceed. What is the problem? Did you try doing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using inner try with resource, after the external try with resource,  init the statement and then use the inner try with resource for the resultSet.

```
public UserBean getUserDevices(final String emailAddress, final String uuid) throws SQLException {
    UserBean userBean = null;

    String query = "SELECT user.id, user.emailAddress, device.uuid, device.active, device.user_id FROM user " +
            "LEFT JOIN device ON user.id = device.user_id AND device.uuid = ? " +
            "WHERE user.emailAddress = ?";

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, uuid);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, emailAddress);

        try(ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();) {
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                if(userBean == null) { // initialize user once while iterating for devices
                    userBean = new UserBean(resultSet.getInt("user.id"), resultSet.getString("user.emailAddress"), null);
                }
                if(resultSet.getString("device.uuid") != null) { // if device exists (it's a LEFT JOIN) then add
                    userBean.getDevices().add(new DeviceBean(0, resultSet.getString("device.uuid"), resultSet.getBoolean("device.active"), resultSet.getInt("device.user_id")));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return userBean;
}
```