# What is a ResultSet that is Closed even mean and definition?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am just trying to understand what ResultSet being closed even means and its actual definition.

before moving on to these follow up questions

> The isClosed() method of the ResultSet interface is used to determine whether the current ResultSet object is closed.

[How can I avoid ResultSet is closed exception in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935511/how-can-i-avoid-resultset-is-closed-exception-in-java)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-you-check-if-a-resultset-is-closed-or-not-in-jdbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Closing frees resources

The Javadoc explains:

> [Closing] releases this `ResultSet` object's database and JDBC resources

After executing a query:

- The database has resources tied up in maintaining the results. These include using memory, locks on tables and/or rows perhaps, etc.
- Your Java app too has resources tied up in maintaining the results. These include memory, network connections, etc.

Closing the [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) frees up the resources on both the server side and the client side.

So make a habit of closing the `ResultSet` as soon as possible, when no longer needed. Do not let it linger. Ditto for other JDBC objects such as [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html), [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), [`Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html), [`RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html), etc.

### Try-with-resources

Generally best to make a habit of using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close these objects. This works on all the JDBC classes marked as [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

This has been covered many times already, so search Stack Overflow to learn more. You will see full example code (some authored by me).

---

Be sure to study [*The Java™ Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle. Specifically, [*Trail: JDBC Database Access*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html).

Related Questions:

[*Try / Try-with-resources and Connection, Statement and ResultSet closing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22671697/642706)

[*How should I use try-with-resources with JDBC?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8066501/642706)

[*Is it a good practice to put ResultSet into a nested try-with-resources statement after Java7?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28494082/642706)

[*try with resources - parameterized PreparedStatements*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49527991/642706)

[*Using "try with resources" for resources created without any reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65059924/642706)

[*JDBC connection try with resources use*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64144096/642706)